# TinyMCE 4, make submenu's parent selectable in link_list

Tags: javascript, tinymce, tinymce-4

I'm updating to TinyMCE 4 and I'm working on the submenu. Based on [this documentation](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Configuration:link_list) I've build a JSON script which returns me a menu:

```
{title: 'Example A', value: '/a'},
{title: 'Example B', value: '/b'},
{title: 'Products', value: '/Products', menu: [
    {title: 'Sub Products 1', value: '/Products/1'},
    {title: 'Sub Products 2', value: '/Products/2'}
    {title: 'Sub Products 3', value: '/Products/3'}
]}
```

This works *almost* like I want. In this example, TinyMCE converts this to this menu:

```
Example A *selectable*
Example B *selectable*
Products >
    Sub Products 1 *selectable*
    Sub Products 2 *selectable*
    Sub Products 3 *selectable*
```

I can't select *Products*. **I want to select Products, how can I make this work?**

I've tried the internet, seems like this isn't common. I've tried to find it in the `plugins/link/plugin.min.js`, but I cant find eventhandling for this. Can't find anything in their documentation either.
If it matters, it's the jQuery version of TinyMCE.

*A comment below suggested this doesnt make sense, So I've updated my example. I want the Products to be selectable. Just think of this page as some sort of general explanation page, or a productoverview.*

Comment: I don't think this makes sense. If you can select option "C", then how would you expect to select option "C1". Based on my experience with menus, TinyMCE is delivering the expected result

Comment: It's hover. But come to think of it, this version should work on mobiles too (though i've build a simple fix for exactly this in our normal front-end navigation)